# Control keyrelease event not working with xte and xvkbd

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

My control keys (both right and left) have been derping for the last month or so, until they stopped working completely. Lazy as I am, rather than sending my computer back to have the keyboard replaced, I had programmed one of my mouse button to act as control on Windows, but as I now mainly use Ubuntu, I figured I could use xbindkeys to use my mouse buttons to trigger the said key.

Now, I have been struggling to bind mouse5 (b:10 on my mouse) to send a keyrelease event with the control key. As of now, here is my config file for xbindkeys:

```
    "xte 'keydown Control_R'"
      b:10

    "xte 'keyup Control_R'"
      b:10 + release
```

The keydown event works fine (and I have to logout/log back in to 'cancel' it) but the keyup with control does nothing, both on xte AND xvkbd. I have tried the keydown then keyup with several other keys, but only control seems to be malfunctionning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1905338&p=11712102#post11712102) while looking for a solution to a slightly different problem.

It seems that using the following should get the behaviour you are looking for. Rather than binding to the keyup and keydown events, use bind directly to the key.

```
"xte 'key Control_L'"
    b:10 + Release
```

Comment: Have been away for a long time, so I didn't see your answer until now. I will try when I have time and get back to you.